# How to delete background of scroll pane in Netbeans java and allow the background of the containing panel to be visible

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans, background

I have a `jTable` named `searchResults` which is contained inside a `jScrollPane (jScrollPane1)`. 
I want to remove all of the unnecessary background where the cells aren't present, as indicated in the next image.

[image]

I have tried this already, but it only makes the background color white (obviously).

```
jScrollPane1.getViewport().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
searchResults.setOpaque(false);
jScrollPane1.setOpaque(false);
```

Please help me with my problem, and tell me where to insert the suggested code snippet in *Netbeans* ide.
I already have a window load action listener where I want the code to be.

Comment: Assuming that you've set the `JTable` as transparant as well, have you tried [`JTable#setFillsViewportHeight`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setFillsViewportHeight-boolean-) and setting it `false`?

Comment: tried, didnt work

Comment: @MadProgrammer   please to see my comment to his majesty aterai

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me using `jScrollPane1.getViewport().setOpaque(false);`

[image: screenshot]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TransparantTableTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JTable searchResults = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(5, 3));
    searchResults.setOpaque(false);
    //searchResults.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(searchResults);
    jScrollPane1.setOpaque(false);
    jScrollPane1.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
    //jScrollPane1.getViewport().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    jScrollPane1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

    TexturePaint texture = makeCheckerTexture();
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
      @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (Objects.nonNull(texture)) {
          Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
          g2.setPaint(texture);
          g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
          g2.dispose();
        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
      }
    };
    p.setOpaque(false);
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    p.add(jScrollPane1);
    return p;
  }
  protected static TexturePaint makeCheckerTexture() {
    int cs = 6;
    int sz = cs * cs;
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(sz, sz, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
    g2.setPaint(new Color(100, 100, 100, 50));
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, sz, sz);
    for (int i = 0; i * cs < sz; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j * cs < sz; j++) {
        if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
          g2.fillRect(i * cs, j * cs, cs, cs);
        }
      }
    }
    g2.dispose();
    return new TexturePaint(img, new Rectangle(sz, sz));
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new TransparantTableTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: @aterai OPs probably meanings only to add (by reduces / stops all Renderers ...) `((DefaultTableCellRenderer)searchResults.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class)).setOpaque(false);`

Comment: @coder123, It works fine for me as well (1+). Did this code work for you??  If so, then how is your code different? Do some basic debugging and post a proper [mcve] when you have a problem. Saying "didn't work" doesn't give anybody any useful information.

Comment: didnt work indicates that the background still shows, whereas i need it to be transparent

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jScrollPane1.getViewport().getView().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: i need it to be transparent, not white